# CARTO popup links redirect back to embed map?

Tags: carto, popup, html, carto-js

When I click a link in the pop-up window the link opens a new tab to the same CARTO map instead of redirecting to the url specified.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="CDB-infowindow CDB-infowindow--light js-infowindow">
<div class="CDB-infowindow-close js-close"></div>
<div class="CDB-infowindow-container">
<div class="CDB-infowindow-bg">
  <div class="CDB-infowindow-inner js-inner">
    <ul class="CDB-infowindow-list js-content">
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">Propery Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{prop_map}}" target=" 
           {{prop_map}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">Soils Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{soils_map}}" target=" 
           {{soils_map}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">FEMA Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{fema_map}}" target=" 
           {{fema_map}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">Stormwater Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{swm_map}}" target=" 
            {{swm_map}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">Sanitary Sewer Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{san_map}}" target=" 
           {{san_map}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">RPA Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{rpa_map}}" target=" 
           {{rpa_map}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">Contour/Topo Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{contourmap}}" target=" 
           {{contourmap}}">Link</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
          <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-title">Zoning Map:</h5>
          <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{zoning_map}}" target=" 
          {{zoning_map}}">Link</h4>

     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="CDB-hook">
  <div class="CDB-hook-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to remove the `target` property or set it as `"_blank" if you want to open a new browser tag. This is a basic HTML, that you can use as an example:

```
    <div class="CDB-infowindow CDB-infowindow--light js-infowindow">
      <div class="CDB-infowindow-close js-close"></div>
      <div class="CDB-infowindow-container">
        <div class="CDB-infowindow-bg">
          <div class="CDB-infowindow-inner js-inner">
            <ul class="CDB-infowindow-list js-content">
              <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
                  <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">url</h5>
                <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title"><a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">{{url}}</a></h4>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="CDB-hook">
          <div class="CDB-hook-inner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image: link-popup]

Comment: I tried this and it still won't follow the links. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you send the .carto to support@carto.com? As soon as we find the solution, I will update my answer (I work at CARTO).